# Print string without escaping characters

Tags: c++

This code:

```
void Controller::write(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << "Writing: [" << str << "] to board." << std::endl; 
    s.write(str);
```

takes a `string` and pushes it over a serial link to a microcontroller. (This works fine). However, when I try to push a like this: `write("ats203?\r")`, the console output looks like this:

```
] to board.ts203?
```

So the `Writing: [a` gets overwritten by the `] to board.` after `std::cout` encounters the `\r` in the string.

How can I print the string as a bunch of characters rather than mangling console output when an escape character is encountered?

EDIT: To clarify.

I *want* my string to be `ats203?\r`. This is because the microcontroller is controlled using a slightly modified version of an [AT command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_phone_AT_commands), and *doesn't accept the command until it reads a `\r`*. When the string is pushed to the microcontroller, it reads the `\r` as a carriage return, and acts on things it read prior to the `\r`.

What I want is to display the string that I've constructed. There is a bunch of other commands elsewhere that get created depending on flags that are set at runtime. So I end up with strings that look something like `ate1\ratv0\rat+OSA=7\rat+OSX=255\r`.

I would like to see what I've constructed and what I'm pushing. I can't do this, because `std::cout` reads the carriage return, acts on it, and mangles my console output.

EDIT: Clarification, again: 
I want `std::cout << "Writing: [" << str << "] to board." << std::endl;` to produce (when `str` is `ats203?\r`):

```
Writing: [ats203?\r] to board.
```

Comment: You can escape the escape character, so `\\r` will leave the string as a literal `"\r"`...not sure if that's what you want or not.

Comment: I don't understand, why is there a `\r` in your string in the first place? What would you like to output instead?

Comment: `\r` is carriage-return character - it'll make "cursor" jump back to the beginning of the line. Perhaps you wanted newline character, `\n`?

Comment: You're *already* not escaping the characters, and what you see is the result of that. You're printing the string as a bunch of characters. Some of those characters happen to do some special things. What did you want to appear instead?

Comment: @prelic I think that's what the OP wants, yes, to display the raw text `\r`.

Comment: Added clarification in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void Controller::write(const std::string& command_string) {

    std::string display_string = std::regex_replace(command_string,std::regex("(\r)"),"\\r");

    std::cout << "Writing: [" << display_string << "] to board.\n"; 
    s.write(command_string);
```

So then `write("ats203?\r")` will literally print out

```
ats203?\r
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to unescape those characters. Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string unescape(const std::string& str){

    std::string res;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i){
        switch (str[i]){
            case '\r':
                res+="\\r";
                break;
            case '\n':
                res+="\\n";
                break;
            case '\\':
                res+="\\\\";
                break;
            case '\t':
                res+="\\t";
                break;
            //add other special characters if necessary...
            default:
                res += str[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main(){ 
    std::cout << unescape("hello\r\nworld\tsome\\words") << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
hello\r\nworld\tsome\\words
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick loop to generate a readable string.

```
std::string str2;
for (int i = 0;  i < str.length();  ++i)
{
    if (str[i] == '\r')
    {
        str2.push_back('\\');
        str2.push_back('r');
    }
    else
        str2.push_back(str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly 'mangling' the characters because of an escape sequence. The '\r' resets your cursor i.e. it is a carriage-return. Hence, your cursor goes to the beginning and whatever is typed now overwrites whatever is there on the line.

You can just erase any instance of `\r` in your string:

```
void Controller::write(const std::string& str) {
    std::string str2(str); //Make a copy of the string as you are getting a const reference
    char remove[] = "\r"; //Add any characters you wish to remove

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(chars); ++i) {
        str2.erase(std::remove(str2.begin(), str2.end(), chars[i]), str2.end());
    }

    std::cout << "Writing: [" << str2 << "] to board." << std::endl; 
    s.write(str);
}
```

**NOTE**: `remove` is a function in `<algorithm>`, so don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`.

*EDIT*: Code to make a copy added, thanks to jrok for pointing that one out :)

Comment: You can't do this, `str` is const.

Comment: Oh.. I did not see that. I'll make a change.

Comment: If there isn't a better solution, I can strip out the offending characters before I display them; I was hoping there was a way I wouldn't have to do that, though.

Comment: @simont You can make a copy of the string and replace carriage return character with '\' and 'r'.

Comment: @simont I guess you were hoping for some way to turn of the special meaning of the carriage return in `cout`? It's actually the console that is acting on the character. You'd have to see if your console has some way to disable this because it's occurring outside your program. I've never heard of such a thing though.

Comment: @RohanPrabhu that code will remove any embedded null characters in addition to carriage returns because `sizeof(remove)` will be the size of the array, including the '\0'. You could replace the initializer with `{'\r'}`. But I'd just go ahead and stick the literal value in the call to `std::remove`. Later if you want to remove more characters you can do 'remove_if'. Also you can use `replace` to insert visible symbols to indicate that something was removed for display. Or regex_replace can replace a character with a printable escape sequence. I'll add an answer showing that.

Comment: @bames53 <quote>I guess you were hoping for some way to turn of the special meaning of the carriage return in cout</quote> Yes, that's a much better way of putting it - I wasn't sure how to word it. I'll look into playing with my console settings - I hadn't thought of that.