# c++ reading file with \ inside the text

Tags: c++, string, escaping, fstream

I need help with a small problem.
I wrote a small program that reads every line of the text inside a .rd file to a string. But inside the text are some \ and when I output the strings the program think that the \ are escape characters.

What can I do to get the original text?

The Program run without an error.

Here is a small snippet of my code:

```
string find="something";
string replace="something2";
string line="";
fstream myfile;
myfile.open ("file.rb");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile,line))
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
        if(line == find)
        {
            myfile << replace;
        }
        else
        {
            myfile << line;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: escape the escape character

Comment: dual : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435667/print-string-without-escaping-characters

Comment: but the character is inside a text I try to read. I can´t change the .rb file to escape every escape character inside the rb

Comment: It seems most unusual that a program would interpret escape sequences *in its output.* How did you find that was happening?

Comment: i just made an cout after the read of every line and the output was not the same as in the input file on every line with an \ inside.

Comment: You're writing to the same file you're reading from...

Comment: the input and output file is the same file. I just need to change one single line of the .rb from over 1000. But i can´t change the line manualy, because I´m not the only person this change is for on there local computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a unicode version of getline or you could try adding `ios::binary` to your stream constructor flags.

See this [article](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) for further info.

However, if you read in a string like "\0" from stdin or a file, it should be treated as two separate characters: '\' and '0'. There is no additional processing that you have to do.

Escaping characters is only used for string/character literals. That is to say, when you want to hard-code something into your source code.